# Retag whmcpanel to whm?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

I just saw a question tagged [whmcpanel](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/whmcpanel) for cPanel's WebHost Manager (WHM). I vote that [whmcpanel](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/whmcpanel) (with 75 questions) be retagged [whm](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/whm) (which has 239 questions)

Arguably both could be merged into [cpanel](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/cpanel) but cpanel questions could be from users who don't have access to WHM, so I don't think that's a good plan. But [whmcpanel](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/whmcpanel) and [whm](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/whm) are redundant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are obviously redundant - Merged and synonymed.